# Laravel 5.2, parsing infinite nested sets using Blade and jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, tree, laravel-blade

I'm looking for a simple way to display a tree with possible infinite number of levels.

I'm using this package:

https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

And by using

```
$root = Category::find($rootId);
$tree = $root->descendants->toTree($root);
```

I can get all of the categories in JSON form.

However I have only not so fun ideas (put a template_a that displays children in foreach loop for first level -the roots- and then in that template  foreach child check for grandchildren, if there are some then display the same template_a again ) about how to parse this data and represent it in a nice tree (collapsible perhaps, something like this would be awesome: https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview).

My hope is that somebody has already done this and I won't have to lose few days on this.

I need to do this in Blade when the page is rendered for the first time and then it would be nice if there is a way to do it in jQuery also (for AJAX updates) but I believe I can figure something out if I got one example. Then I will know what exactly am I searching for and how to approach the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something alongside this will work in Blade, I still need to figure out the jQuery/javascript/whatever framework will you use for AJAX calls.

```
@foreach ($categories->children as $child)
  @include('categories.myPartial')
@endofreach
```

and the `categories/myPartial.blade.php` is something like this

```
  @foreach($child->children as $child)
    {{ $child->name }}
    @include('categories.myPartial')
  @endofreach
```

This is just a rough example but it should work. My code is bit more complex so I decided not to copy/paste all of it here. If anybody have any questions feel free to ask.

This is nice and readable but the way I see it, it will do N queries where N is the number of descendants.

I'm still looking for a way to optimize this.